Bash loop on two sets of files simultaneously
I have two sets of files in the same directory :
1.bam 
2.bam
3.bam

and
1.txt
2.txt
3.txt

I need to run a command where 1.bam and 1.txt are interpreted together, and so on..
I tried looping through array indices :
bam=(*.bam)
ids=(*.txt)

for i in ${#bam[@]}; do     
 f=${bam[i]}    
 e=${ids[i]}
 samtools view -N $e $f 
done

And with parallel :
parallel --dry-run 'samtools view -N {1} {2} > {2.}.fasta' ::: *txt ::: *bam

With --dry-run , I can see that loops 3 times (3 sets of files * 3 loop) ; I just need one.
Any help?

Loop through the indices e.g.: for i in "${!bam[@]}"

Simple.. Thanks.

What about the parallel command? Do you see something wrong?

Just pass the .bam files to GNU Parallel and derive the corresponding text file the same as you derive the output file parallel 'samtools view -N {1.}.txt {1} > {1.}.fasta' ::: *.bam

When to wrap quotes around a shell variable?

Possible duplicate of "Iterate over two arrays simultaneously in bash". But what if the two file lists don't match up properly (e.g. if there's an extra .txt file with no matching .bam file, or vice versa)? Would it be better to just iterate over just the .bam files, and generate the matching .txt filename by substitution (see this answer)?

If some files were to be missing, the sets will be misaligned.

Of course, but I am sure about the number of paired files.

I’m voting to close this question because the poster didn't use http://shellcheck.net as directed by the [tag:bash] tag.

First, ${#bam[@]} reports the number of elements in bam.
As Jetchisel mentioned in the comments, what you want is "${!bam[@]}" which returns the indices.
$: touch {1..3}.{bam,txt}
$: ls
1.bam  1.txt  2.bam  2.txt  3.bam  3.txt

$: bam=(*.bam); ids=(*.txt)
$: echo "${bam[@]} ${ids[@]}"
1.bam 2.bam 3.bam 1.txt 2.txt 3.txt

$: for i in ${#bam[@]}; do f=${bam[i]}; e=${ids[i]}; echo "i='$i' f='$f' e='$e'"; done
i='3' f='' e=''

$: echo "#:'${#bam[@]}' !:'${!bam[@]}'"
#:'3' !:'0 1 2'

$: for i in ${!bam[@]}; do f=${bam[i]}; e=${ids[i]}; echo "i='$i' f='$f' e='$e'"; done
i='0' f='1.bam' e='1.txt'
i='1' f='2.bam' e='2.txt'
i='2' f='3.bam' e='3.txt'

This does assume the arrays will be truly parallel. I leave any error checking on that to you unless you ask for a deeper dive into it.
There are other ways to approach it. If you are assuming true parallel arrays, you can also back into it by iterating one and string-hacking the other.
$: for b in ${bam[@]}; do echo "b='$b' t='${b%.bam}.txt'"; done
b='1.bam' t='1.txt'
b='2.bam' t='2.txt'
b='3.bam' t='3.txt'

But you can interpolate the filenames explicitly with brace expansion -
$: for i in ${!bam[@]}; do echo "samtools view -N" $i.{bam,txt}; done
samtools view -N 0.bam 0.txt
samtools view -N 1.bam 1.txt
samtools view -N 2.bam 2.txt

So I'd do it something like this:
for i in ${!bam[@]}
do samtools view -N $i.{bam,txt} > $i.fasta 2> $i.log & 
done

As a habit I'd usually quote those vars, but in this case it's all integer indices, and quoting the {bam,txt} breaks it so you'd have to exclude it from your otherwise (circumstantially) unrequired quotes, so I've just left them off in this occasion.

"$i".{bam,txt} quotes the part which needs quoting.

Yes, but it is just a digit, lol

It would still be nice to have correct quoting for the benefit of future visitors whose use case may be slightly different.

100% agree. Thanks.

Well, thank you for your help.

Here's a pipeline-y way to do it:
printf "%s\n" *.{bam,txt} \
| sort \
| while IFS= read -r bamfile; IFS= read -r txtfile; do
    echo "do something with '${bamfile}' and '${txtfile}'"
  done

do something with '1.bam' and '1.txt'
do something with '2.bam' and '2.txt'
do something with '3.bam' and '3.txt'

Assumes none of your filenames contain newlines. This pipeline can use null delimeter instead of newline though
printf "%s\0" *.{bam,txt} \
| sort -z \
| while IFS= read -d '' -r bamfile; IFS= read -d '' -r txtfile; do
    echo "do something with '${bamfile}' and '${txtfile}'"
  done


Interesting, thanks for that.
